# How to sort a HashMap with key,value pair from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

Hi i have a ArrayList of HashMap and i need the HashMap to be sorted by its key,Value.

```
ArrayList<HashMap> newList = new ArrayList();
```

loop start:

```
HashMap hashData = new HashMap();

hashData.put("name", "string-studentname");
hashData.put("mark", "int-studentmark");

newList.add(hashData);
```

loop end:

I need the newList to be sorted by the key-mark.

How do i get it?

Comment: Your list contains only one element. And that element is a hashmap with one name and one mark, because you overwrote them for each new student. Did you mean to create multiple hashmaps?

Comment: And your map contains only 2 entries: `name` and `mark`

Comment: if the ArrayList is appended in a loop, how will i get it ?

Comment: Read the docs: [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html), especially [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function))

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple entries in your `ArrayList` and the key is the same, you can just sort via:

```
newList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.get("mark")));
```

Assuming you're typing the map properly:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hashData = new HashMap<>();
hashData.put("mark", 1);
```